# VBA adding to array at runtime

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript

I am trying to create an int array at runtime from results of a record set.

```
Do While Not rstSearchResult.EOF

 If rstSearchResult(ID) = blah Then 
  'Add this Id rstSearchResult(ID) to Array
 End If

 Call rstSearchResult.MoveNext()
Loop
```

What I need is that same result as this will give me `Array(35588, 35589, 35595)`

Comment: What does your current code produce?

Comment: I don't know how many numbers will match the condition so how would you add to an array with no upper bound. Thats my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dim myIntArray() as Integer
Dim intDimension as Integer

intDimension = 0

Do While Not rstSearchResult.EOF

 If rstSearchResult(ID) = blah Then   
  'Add this Id rstSearchResult(ID) to Array
  REDIM PRESERVE myIntArray(intDimension)
  myIntArray(intDimension) = rstSearchResult(ID)
  intDimension = intDimension +1
 End If

 Call rstSearchResult.MoveNext()
Loop
```

Comment: This should work, just note that as the array gets large, it turns into a huge memory hog.

Comment: The problem isn't memory hogging, anyway. The issue is that this is now a O(n^2) algorithm because you're copying the array into a new array at each iteration.

Answer (score 6):

When I need to copy from a Recordset to an array, it's a little bit more efficient to ReDim the array to the size you want beforehand instead of ReDiming it inside the loop.

```
Dim myIntArray() as Integer
Dim intDimension as Integer

rstSearchResult.Filter = "ID = " & blah
ReDim myIntArray(rstSearchResult.RecordCount - 1)

intDimension = 0
Do Until rstSearchResult.EOF
    myIntArray(intDimension) = rstSearchResult!ID
    intDimension = intDimension + 1
    rstSearchResult.MoveNext
Loop
```

Note that for RecordCount to work you need to open the recordset as static.

```
rstSearchResult.Open "tblSearchResult", cnn, adOpenStatic
```

Comment: It makes sense to ReDim outside of the loop. So I ReDim once before the loop to the size of the record set, and again at the end to resize the array to the amount of result matched. Thanks Tmdean

Answer (score 1):

When I do VBA in excel I have a class I use for the DB accessing in it I have a function that returns the recordset to an array. Hope the below helps.

```
Public Function RSToArray(ByVal oRS, Optional ByVal iRows, Optional ByVal iStart, Optional ByVal aFieldsArray)
    If iRows = 0 Then iRows = adGetRowsRest
    If iStart = 0 Then iStart = adBookmarkfirst

    RSToArray = ""  ' return a string so user can check For (IsArray)

    If IsObject(oRS) And oRS.State = adStateOpen Then
        If Not oRS.BOF And Not oRS.EOF Then
            If IsArray(aFieldsArray) Then
                RSToArray = oRS.GetRows(iRows, iStart, aFieldsArray)
            Else
                If iRows <> adGetRowsRest Or iStart <> adBookmarkfirst Then
                    RSToArray = oRS.GetRows(iRows, iStart)
                Else
                    RSToArray = oRS.GetRows()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```